# Get members nickname of MUC Room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

Is there a way to get all nicknames of a MUC Room with an ejabberd server?

I'm trying with:

```
<iq from='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
  id='member3'
  to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
  type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
   <item affiliation='member'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

but I obtain only jid without nicknames:

```
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
  id='member3'
  to='crone1@shakespeare.lit/desktop'
  type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin'>
    <item affiliation='member'
      jid='hag66@shakespeare.lit'
      role='participant'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Comment: I have a "members-only" room. I would discover nicknames also when members are offline.

Answer (score 1):

On [6.5 Querying for Room Items](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-roomitems) from [XEP 0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) when you send

```
<iq from='$user-name@$user-server/$user-resorce'
    id='someid'
    to='$chat-room-to-query@$chatserver'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

You have the following description

> An implementation **MAY** return a list of existing occupants if that information is **publicly available**, or return no list at all if this information is kept private.(emphasis mine)

if the room is public them you get

```
<iq from='$chat-room-to-query@$chatserver'
    id='someid'
    to='$user-name@$user-server/$user-resorce'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'>
    <item jid='$chat-room-to-query@$chatserver/$firstnick'/>
    <item jid='$chat-room-to-query@$chatserver/$secondnick'/>
    <...>
  </query>
</iq>
```

From my knowledge ejabberd implements this correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is if is there a way to get members nicknames and not occupants nicknames. I have a "members-only" room and its members can be offline.

Comment: Hey, did you find a resolution to this?